# What does Module(__name__) do?

Tags: python

I am puzzled by this line of code:

```
email = Module(__name__)
```

I would guess this is simply creating an alias to refer to the module that I am in? If not, then what does this do?

Comment: It's going to depend on what Module` is defined as...

Comment: So Module has no general meaning in Python?

Comment: No, there's no built-in named `Module`. It looks to be a class based on the fact that it's capitalized, but that's just a guess.

Comment: `Module` is a name that you must have defined before, either by importing it or by defining it yourself. So it in fact depends on the rest of your code. Alone, it gives the error `NameError: name 'Module' is not defined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Within a [module](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#modules), the module’s name (as a string) is available as the value of the global variable `__name__`.

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> it.__name__
'itertools'
```

But `email = Module(__name__)` will raise a `NameError`: (name 'Module' is not defined). and if you defined the name `Module` for example use `itertools(__name__)` as it is not callable it raise a `TypeError`.

So as `__name__` is a module attribute you cant pass it alone .

Also you can find `__name__` in the `dir()` function result that is used to find out which names a module defines.

```
>>> dir(itertools)
['__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'chain', 'combinations', 'combinations_with_replacement', 'compress', 'count', 'cycle', 'dropwhile', 'groupby', 'ifilter', 'ifilterfalse', 'imap', 'islice', 'izip', 'izip_longest', 'permutations', 'product', 'repeat', 'starmap', 'takewhile', 'tee']
```

Comment: But what does Module() do, and what would it mean to give Module the __name__ of the current module? Does this line of code create an alias or what?

Comment: @cerhovice the name `Module` has not any meaning in python as i say if your module was not callable `Module(__name__)` will raise a NameError: name 'Module' is not defined.

Comment: It's theoretically possible OP did `from types import ModuleType as Module` or something of that nature.  Surprisingly, [`ModuleType()` can be instantiated by hand](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/types.html#types.ModuleType).

Comment: @Kevin yes its possible , any way i think explain all thing clearly . so you think what can i add to answer to be more complete ?